# Webforms Warning message: Update the Input Mask Library

Tags: webforms, 10

I've been looking at the Warning message to download and update the Input Mask library to version 5.0.x for some time now.

[image]

I've tried all the suggestions at https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/webform/webform-libraries. None of them makes the message go away on my local ddev installation.

/admin/reports/status says `JQuery:input Mask 5.0.8 (Installed)` when jquery.inputmask is in docroot/libraries, or `jQuery: Input Mask 5.0.8 (CDN)` when the library is being loaded via a CDN.

If I add an exit(); after webform_requirements is called in webform.install.requirements.inc or if I comment out webform_requirements completely, the message still prints.

Does anyone have a new suggestion? I'd like this message to go away.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the answer was to click the X in the upper right corner of the warning message one time to make it go away forever.

From what I can tell, the persistence of this message may have been because of `$help_manager->addNotification()` or perhaps `hook_webform_message_custom()`. I found no record of webform_update_8187() in the database.